# What's unique about the most commonly used hetero-cyclic elements?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have question about hetero-cycles: Why do we use (the most common hetero-cyclic elements) nitrogen, oxygen, sulfur as hetero compounds most of time?

Answer (score 3):

A possible reason for this is that heterocycles with O, N or S are often easier to obtain and more stable than the corresponding compounds which contain other main group elements as heteroatoms. [Phosphole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphole), for example, is less stable than furan, pyrrole and thiophene because of its lower aromaticity. [Borole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borole), the structural analog with the lighter heteroatom B, has not yet been isolated in unsubstituted form. Ring strain and the stability of X-C and X-H bonds (X = heteroatom) also need to be considered. Bond lengths tend to increase with heavier heteroatoms. With decreasing electronegativity of X in relation to C, the X-C bond becomes less covalent and is more prone to be cleaved by hydrolysis, for example.